# <h:selectOneMenu> selectOne item and rendered an "inputText"

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I have a dropdownbox and an inputText. Here is my xhtml codes:

```
<h:panelGroup id="inputs">
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{tabBean.refundCharge}" name="reCharge">
    <f:selectItems value="#{tabBean.reChargeList}" />
    <f:ajax render="inputs" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>


    <p:inputText value="#{tabBean.refundDescr}"  rendered="#{tabBean.refundCharge == 'Item2'}"/>
</h:panelGroup>
```

And this is TabBean :

```
 private String            refundCharge;

    public String[] getReChargeList() {


        ResourceBundle config = ResourceBundle.getBundle("config");
        String reChargeList=   "Item1 % Item2 % Item3";
        String delimeter = "[%]";
        String[] reChargeDescr = reChargeList.split(delimeter);

        return reChargeDescr;
    }
```

The inputText is not shown.When I clicked Item2 value from the dropDownList, The input Text must be shown. But it isn't work by these codes.

It must be shown just when I clicked Item2. Where is the error?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean?Purpose of your code is to show the inputText, so you actually said it does work...

Comment: in my code, there are one listbox and one input text. I rendered it, So when I select item2, the inoputText must be shown.

Comment: is your inputText shown or not, you r confusing others by stating two conflicting statements.. if not shown then you want only it to be shown ???

Comment: The inputText is not shown!. But when I select Item2, it must be shown. But it doesn't shown when click, so where is the problem. Sorry if I conflicting you.

Comment: @Abhinav what he wants is to show the inputText only when 'Item2' is selected in selectOneMenu.

Comment: You're missing a `{` in your rendered condition (inputText)

Comment: first of all add one brace in rendered... as 'rendered="#{tabBean.refundCharge == 'Item2'}"'

Comment: sorry @TNT i didnt see your post..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a space before and after every `%` in the `reChargeList`. So effectively the split values are `"Item1 "`, `" Item2 "` and `" Item3"`. The `" Item2 "` does not equal to `"Item2"` which you've specified in `rendered` attribute and hence it will never be rendered.

Remove those spaces or change your split delimiter to `\\s*%\\s*`